# Converting from do() to tap() from Angular 2 to Angular 6

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am trying to implement Server Side Pagination for a Grid in `Angular 6` with `Kendo Grid`

The code below is from `Angular 2` which I have taken from the below site

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/server-side-paging-in-kendo-grid-for-angular-2/

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {  
  this.grid.dataStateChange  
      .do(({ skip, take }: DataStateChangeEvent) => {  
          this.skip = skip;  
          this.pageSize = take;  
      })  
      .subscribe(x => this.service.query(x));  
}
```

Because I am using `Angular 6`, it is expecting `tap` instead of `do` in the above code.

Currently I am getting red swiggly for `do` and the error says as below

`Property 'do' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter<DataStateChangeEvent>'`

How can I convert it into a usable code by using `tap` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tree shaking purposes RxJS changed its synthax from 6.0 upwards.

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {  
  this.grid.dataStateChange
      .pipe(
          tap(({ skip, take }: DataStateChangeEvent) => {  
              this.skip = skip;  
              this.pageSize = take;  
          })
      ) 
      .subscribe(x => this.service.query(x));  
}
```